# Copy a json nested dictionary to csv file

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary, nested

I need to copy the following nested dictionary in json from an api to a csv file

```
{
 "result": [{
               "short_description": "I am getting bluescreen error",
               "sys_id": "39b5f8c2376ede007520021a54990e5c",
               "opened_at": "2016-04-04 05:19:53",
               "number":"INC0258523"
             },
             {
               "short_description": "laptop crashed with a blue screen",
               "sys_id": "da0095380f43d200a4f941fce1050eeb",
               "opened_at":"2016-04-25 06:33:52",
               "number":"INC0259067"
             }, 
             {
               "short_description": "Laptop not booting",
               "sys_id": "ecf9c9b00f43d200a4f941fce1050e17",
               "opened_at": "2016-04-25 06:07:16",
               "number": "INC0259061"
             }]
}
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
  with open('D:/file.csv', 'wb') as f:  
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, data.keys())   
        w.writerow(data)
```

I get the following result in single cell of the csv file

```
[{"short_description":"I am getting bluescreen error","sys_id":"39b5f8c2376ede007520021a54990e5c","opened_at":"2016-04-04 05:19:53","number":"INC0258523"},{"short_description":"laptop crashed with a blue screen","sys_id":"da0095380f43d200a4f941fce1050eeb","opened_at":"2016-04-25 06:33:52","number":"INC0259067"},{"short_description":"Laptop not booting","sys_id":"ecf9c9b00f43d200a4f941fce1050e17","opened_at":"2016-04-25 06:07:16","number":"INC0259061"}]}
```

Whereas I need it to be in the format where keys short_description, sys_id, opened_at, number are column names and their values as corresponding column data.

Comment: What is `data`? If it is the json string, you need to decode it first using `json.loads(data)`

Comment: Before writing you have to serialize your data into a list where every item represents a cell.

Comment: data is a json string and i have used json.loads(data).

Comment: how do i serialize it ? @Klaus

Comment: That depends on what you expects as output. You should add a sample to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the row dictionaries.  Right now you are using the top level `'result'` dict to feed the csv writer.

```
  with open('D:/file.csv', 'wb') as f:  
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, data['result'][0].keys())   
        for row in data['result']:
            w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Now I just need the column names

Comment: ``data['result'][0].keys()`` are the column names.